# Is there a GUI tool for MacOS that allows to print labels from SQL databases

Tags: sql, database, macos, sqlite, user-interface

I am looking for a GUI tool on Mac which allows users to browse contents of a relatively simple SQL database (only 2-3 tables) and which allows them to print selected records in a specific layout on labels.
This database ran previously on MsAccess and we would like to have it as SQL. However, non IT-professionals should easily be able to print those labels.
If anybody knows a tool for this (except filemaker), please let me know.

Thanks a lot,
Philipp

Comment: This is Off-topic. apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest OpenOffice for a "mailmerge" like label printing.
If You need a more robust "report" oriented solution You can take a look at jasper reports and ireport both have release for OSx.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer